# PHP namespaces, already in namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces

I am learning PHP namespaces. There is one small piece i do not understand, example:

```
use Hello\Hello2;

require 'Hello/Hello2/Hello.php';

$h = new Hello2\Hello();

echo $h->sayHello();
```

To me, when i say: `use Hello\Hello2` it seems to me i am in namespace Hello2 and so i do not understand why i have to instantiate my object like this:

$h = new Hello2\Hello();

Why not just like this (cause i am already in namespace Hello2)

$h = new Hello();

Regards,

Marcel

Comment: with autoload like using composer, you can do this. In your demo,  maybe you need require first, then use. You can use some class within same namespace.

Comment: A `use` statement isn't like a `cd` shell command. It doesn't *switch* current namespace, it creates an alias.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that with these `use` statements you declare aliases (implicit, like in your example OR explicit).

So when you're writing

```php
use Hello\Hello2;
```

you're basically writing

```php
use Hello\Hello2 as Hello2;
```

As in you declare the alias `Hello2` for the namespace `Hello\Hello2`. Think of it as a search and replace mechanism.

If you want to use directly the class name, you will have to use the fully qualified name of the class:

```php
use Hello\Hello2\Hello;

...

new Hello();
```

**UPDATE:**

> Why not just like this (cause i am already in namespace Hello2)

No, you're not in the Hello2 namespace. In order to "be" in a namespace, you have to use the `namespace` statement. You can be in a single namespace at a time, but you can declare multiple `use` statements, which again are "just" aliases (or shortcut declarations if you wish) for other namespaces, classes, functions or even constants.

More details in the PHP manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php.